# Why does hovering over a DateTimeOffset display the Hour value only?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I hover over this `DateTimeOffset` variable, only the `Hour` value is displayed:

[image]

I want to have the full `DateTimeOffset` back. Where is this actually coming from and how can I set/reset it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `Hour` pinned.  Unpin it and it should restore back to showing the full `DateTimeOffset` value.

Expand `dt`, and you should see `Hour` is pinned at the top of the list it displays.  Click the pin icon and it will unpin it:

[image: pin icon]

Comment: So simple, yet so hard to find... Usually I pinned the values.
What totally caught me off guard is that this also changes how the type is displayed in the "Watch" window.

What a relief :) Thank you

Comment: @okipol yea I think the Pinning works across the IDE in various spots as one, so pinning it down in a watch window also pins it in the editor.